# How to get the forwarding status and number?

Tags: android

I want to read the phone setting to see if forwarding is enabled or not. And if it is
enabled then I want to get the number that calls are forwarded to. I DO NOT want to use
"PhoneStateListener" because the forwarding can be activated before my app installation.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a broadcast call and register it and try to get the outgoing call as shown below :

```
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static String numberToCall;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("CallRecorder", "CallBroadcastReceiver::onReceive got Intent: " + intent.toString());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            numberToCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.d("CallRecorder", "CallBroadcastReceiver intent has EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER: " + numberToCall);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when the onReceive will be fired? And how should I register the reciever? Is it correct: Intent i = registerReceiver(x, y) ? If yes then what is x and y? x is the reciver, right? and then I do not know what is y?